# request.user.is_authenticated is false on certain HTML on certain pages but not in views

Tags: python, django, authentication

Most pages on this website I'm creating for practice
`{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` go through as true.
But there is one page that always returns this as false (I've pasted that section of code below). Even though in views.py the function that controls that page, show when I run

`print(request.user.is_authenticated)`

outputs: true

HTML:

```
{% extends "page0/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
 
                <h2>{{ listing.listingTitle  }}</h2>
                 {% ifequal listing.validURL listing.valid %}
                    <img src="{{listing.picture}}"  alt="picture!" style="width:150px">
                 {% else %}
                    <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-07-26/no%20thumbnail%20found%20suggestion.png"  alt="no picture!" style="width:150px">
                    <p>NOTE: no image provided</p>
                 {% endifequal %}
                 
                 <p>{{bidPrice}} $</p>
                  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <form action="{% url 'bid' listing.listingTitle %}" method = "post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{form2}}
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="button">
                      </form>
                    {% else %}
                    Not signed in. <a href = "\register">Sign in or create an account </a>
                    
                     {% endif %}
            
                </div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from markdown import Markdown
from django.contrib.messages.api import success
from django.contrib import messages
import os.path
from .models import User
import datetime
import time
import validators
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

from django import forms
from . import util

from .models import Listing as Listina

currentGlobalName = ''
currentBid = 0
currentUser = ''

def listing(request, name, num='0'):
    data = ''

    listing = Listina.objects.get(listingTitle=name)
    form2 = BidForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form2.is_valid():
            num = form2.cleaned_data['price']

    bid = listing.price
    
    if num > bid:
        bid = num
        # listing.price.update(price = num)
        Listina.objects.filter(listingTitle=name).update(price=bid)

    currentUser = str(request.user)
    index = currentUser.find(' ')
    currentUser = currentUser[0:index]
    print("REQUESTED USER AND ABUSER", request.user)
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)

    currentBid = bid

    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
        "listing": listing,
        "bidPrice": bid,
        "form2": form2,
        "user": currentUser
    })
```

I'm not sure why even is user is authenticated and views is also showing the user is authenticated when I print out, that it's showing up as false on the actually html. Then none of the conditionals work on the HTML page.

Comment: Your `currentUser` is a string not object. It should be `"user": request.user`

Comment: I mean you should change your context in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a django project there is such a thing as template context processor, context processor makes available variables, that we create in our code in templates.

'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', sets the request user variable, and makes it available in every django template.

In your code you have overwritten django user variable with a string variable currentUser, the currentUser string does not have is_authenticated property, hence you get False.

Comment: awesome @alv2017: that did it!

Answer (score 1):

user object is exisiting in global context. You overriden the user object with a text string.

```
currentUser = str(request.user)

"user": currentUser
```

It is not user object anymore. It is just a simple string. Thats why you got the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

You can use decorators in your views for deny any unauthenticated user. You don't need to be use `{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}` in your html. just add [decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) in your views.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required  
def listing(request, name, num='0'):
    .........
```

Comment: That is not the issue here.

Comment: NKSM  then what is the issue ? explain little bit. I will try to help you

Comment: @boyenec it is not the same thing. How do you plan to do with *login_required* if you want to do something when user is authenticated and do some another thing if not?

Comment: @boyonec Is it or not, doesnt matter. **login_required** and **user.is_authenticated** are not the same thing. **Their functionality are different**. One is not another's replacement

Comment: @obayhan  I can't agree with your commnet. `user.is_authenticated` means when Django authenticated the user and how django  authenticated user ??? once user is login django can authenticated the user.

Comment: @boyonec **user.is_authenticated** executes a code block if returns true and  executes another code block if it returns false.

but **login_required** redirects the whole page if it fails. I think you must read django documentation carefully

Comment: @obayhan yeah agreed now :)